# How to explain this glibc modification on libpthread?

Tags: pthreads, glibc, yocto

We found an issue while we upgrade Yocto from 1.7 to 2.2. 
App below behaves differently on newer glibc, it always got stuck on pthread_cond_destroy on glibc2.25, while on glibc2.20 it ends well.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
void *thread1(void *);
void *thread2(void *);
int main(void)
{
     pthread_t t_a;
     pthread_t t_b;
     pthread_create(&t_a,NULL,thread1,(void *)NULL);
     pthread_create(&t_b,NULL,thread2,(void *)NULL);
     sleep(1);

     pthread_cond_destroy(&cond);
     pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
     exit(0);
}
void *thread1(void *args)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond,&mutex);
}
void *thread2(void *args)
{
}
```

After investigation I find a glibc commit here:
https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;f=sysdeps/arm/nptl/bits/pthreadtypes.h;h=ed19993b5b0d05d62cc883571519a67dae481a14, which seems to be the reason.

We noticed the comment of __pthread_cond_destroy, it mentioned:

> A correct program must make sure that no waiters are blocked on the
>   condvar when it is destroyed.
>
> It must also ensure that no signal or broadcast are still pending to
>   unblock waiters.
>
> and destruction that is concurrent with still-active waiters is
>   probably neither common nor performance critical.

From my perspective it brings in a defect. But glibc team seems to have a good reason. Could anybody explain whether this modification is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_destroy.html):

```
Attempting to destroy a condition variable upon which other threads
are currently blocked results in undefined behavior.
```

> From my perspective it brings in a defect.

Your program depended on undefined behavior. Now you pay the price of doing so.

Comment: I admit that the programme didn't follow the standard, but in the link, it also claims:

"The [EBUSY] ... and caused an error return prior to modifying the state of the condition variable specified by cond."  "
The implementation has detected an attempt to destroy the object referenced by cond while it is referenced (for example, while being used in a pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait()) by another thread"  
As per the stardard, it should return error, but not pending there.

Comment: It also says: "The [EBUSY] and [EINVAL] error checks, *if implemented*, shall act as if ...". The library is not *obligated* to detect undefined behavior in your program.

Comment: This answer is correct.  Your program had an error - that error didn't cause any symptoms before, but now it does.